# Eclipse forgot all my projects?

Tags: java, eclipse

That topic might have sounded a little silly, so forgive that, but here's what's happening:

I have several folder in my Package Explorer that contain several projects I've been working on.

The problem is that Eclipse seems to not find my projects within my folder.

[image]

Those folder-like icons are suppose to be double-clickable to reveal my projects...

But after I closed up last time, they won't show up again.

None of them!

And they're all there. In the Workspace I've always used. All the files, all the folders, all the everything.

Why can't Eclipse find them?

I've tried creating a new Workspace, as well as importing the old projects over again, but then I got the error that these projects already exist.

I've restarted Eclipse, restarted my computer and anything else I can think of restarting.

The biggest issue I have is that now I can't access any of my work, and thus can't keep working on it!

Could anyone be kind enough to take a stab at how I should go about fixing this?

Please, be gentle. I'm a little green to all this.

Comment: *I've tried creating a new Workspace, as well as importing the old projects over again, but then I got the error that these projects already exist.* - yu shouldn't get this error in a new workspace.

Comment: Perhaps that was a little unclarity from my side, I didn't try to import them into the new Workspace, just the old one. See, if it was doable, I'd rather not make a new Workspace, as all my setting and shortcuts and preferences would be gone...

Comment: delete everything in the current workspace from the package explorer and re-import all projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go into arcives in the top-left corner and click on projects to see if it's the correct project folder.

Another thing you can do is to check if the project-files are still in the folder where you have your workspace. If they are there it can help to create a "new" project with the same name and all the files will automaticlly be in the project again. :)

Comment: Phew, that did it! I will have to re-create every project I ever made, but at least it works now! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Nps! Happened to me alot when I started using Eclipse and it took a while for me to figure it out. :)